# lower bound the distance between two varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, numerical-methods, smooth-manifolds, computer-algebra-systems, complex-manifolds

$\DeclareMathOperator{\complex}{\mathbb{C}}$ Let $X,Y \subseteq \complex^n$ be homogeneous, smooth, irreducible, closed algebraic sets with $X \cap Y=\{0\}$. I would like to numerically lower bound the quantity

\begin{align}
\inf_{\substack{x\in X, y \in Y\\ ||x||_2=1,||y||_2=1}} ||x-y||_2.\hspace{3in} (*)
\end{align}

(I have chosen the L2 norm for concreteness, but any norm will do). It is easy to see that $(*)$ will be non-zero.

In my particular case, $X$ is a linear subspace and $Y$ is a degree-two determinantal(-ish) variety. I have been working with Macaulay2, so a possible implementation with this software would be amazing.

Also, is there a way to phrase this question  more elegantly, perhaps in terms of minimizing the distance between the projectivizations of $X,Y$ with respect to a projective metric? Please forgive my ignorance of projective metrics. I would appreciate an introductory reference in this vein.

Comment: This sounds related to the kinds of problems people study in algebraic statistics, in particular Sturmfels and collaborators. Maybe something like this is a reasonable starting point: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06544.pdf

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti Thank you, this is a good starting point. Might you have any insight into the question I ask in my last paragraph? I suspect there is a more succinct way to phrase what I'm looking for.